# How to withdraw custom ERC20 token from smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have successfully created a contract that interacts with my custom token and now I want to be able to also withdraw those tokens from my contract.

I have tested the following code with no success and I am looking for someone to point my in the right direction:

```
    function ContractOwnerTokenWithdraw(address _to, uint amount) public 
    OnlyContractOwner {
        require(amount > 0 && amount < token.balanceOf(address(this)), "Error: Required value is bigger than existing amount.");
        token.transferFrom(address(this), _to, amount);
    }
```

*Where token is the token I am interacting with.

Comment: Did you approve the funds before calling `ContractOwnerTokenWithdraw`?

Comment: Even if you own both contracts, the token and the other, you still need to approve ?! I did not know that. I thought you can interact  directly from etherscan and withdraw

Comment: Yes, it always requires approval